# ArrayList desending order using compare method

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare and prepare a array list based on descending order of date, I use the below code but get result which is ascending.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //HistoryBank(String amount, String date, String month)
    ArrayList<HistoryBank> arraylist = new ArrayList<HistoryBank>();
       arraylist.add(new HistoryBank("223", "20141111", "20141111"));
       arraylist.add(new HistoryBank("245", "20131111", "20131111"));
       arraylist.add(new HistoryBank("209", "20151111", "20151111"));

   Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<HistoryBank>() {

            public int compare(HistoryBank s1, HistoryBank s2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(s1.getDate())
                        .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2.getDate()));
            }

       });
       for(HistoryBank str: arraylist){
            System.out.println(str.getDate());
       }
}
```

i get my result as

```
 20131111
 20141111
 20151111
```

but i want result in descending order like

```
 20151111
 20141111
 20131111
```

Please help

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the parameters in the compare method (i.e. compare `s2.getDate()` to `s1.getDate()`):

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<HistoryBank>() {

        public int compare(HistoryBank s1, HistoryBank s2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(s2.getDate())
                    .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s1.getDate()));
        }

   });
```

Comment: Or leave them as they are and multiply with -1. I like that because it's making it more obvious what the intention was.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're dealing with already existing `Comparators` that you can't change, there's also `Collections.reverse(List);` and `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator);`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- If you already have a sorted list, use [Collections.reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29):
- Create a `Comparator` that returns the opposite than the original one. Better yet, create a `Comparator` that takes your original `Comparator` and changes the sign of the return value. Better yet, use the already built-in [Collections.reverseOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) Comparator.